# Tkinter - Thread communication and shared result - with progressbar

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, progress-bar

I am building an interface in Tkinter in which the main window (let's call it 'root') contains a button (say, 'create'). Furthermore, assume I have already defined a function 'f'. I would like to create the following effect: clicking on 'create' would execute 'f' in the background and at the same time open an indeterminate progress bar in a new window. Moreover, and this is the tricky part for me, I want the progress bar to close automatically after 'f' is done executing. How can I achieve this? Could you please provide a minimal working example? I think that key lies on constructing a proper function to pass as 'command' option to 'create'.

This is what I have thus far. It is not even running properly, as the progress bar runs indefinitely and the task starts being executed only after the progress bar is closed (or after closing 'root'). However, it feels like this is really close, and there is some small issue that I should fix but that I cannot see:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import threading
import time

root = Tk() # Main window

def create_command():

    stop_flag = threading.Event()  # create a flag to stop the progress bar

    def f():
        # function to do some task
        print("Starting task...")
        time.sleep(5)  # simulate some time-consuming task
        print("Task complete.")
        stop_flag.set()  # set the stop flag to indicate that progress_check() should stop

    progress_bar_window = Toplevel(root)  # Progress bar window

    progress_bar = Progressbar(progress_bar_window, orient= 'horizontal', length= 300, mode= 'indeterminate') # Create progress bar
    progress_bar.pack()

    progress_bar.start()  

    def progress_check():         
        
        # function to run an infinite loop
        while not stop_flag.is_set():
            
            print("Running infinite loop...")
            time.sleep(1) 
        progress_bar.stop()
        progress_bar_window.destroy() 

    progress_bar_window.mainloop() # Start mainloop for progress bar window
    
    # create separate threads to run the functions
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=f, args=())
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=progress_check, args=())
    
    thread1.start()  # start executing f    
    thread2.start()  # start the progress_check   
     

    # wait for f to finish before stopping the infinite loop
    thread2.join()
    stop_flag.set()  # set the stop flag to indicate that progress_bar() should stop

create_button = Button(root, text= "Create", command= create_command)
create_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you know that there are already examples on the web, including this site? It would help us to write a better answer with the things you have trouble with. Also it would be nice to know if you plan to use the button multiple times while f is running or you want to just reuse it after done or something else. Also do you need other information from the running thread, besides when it is done, some data an object or whatever?

Comment: Hi @Thingamabobs! I could not find an example on the web similar to what I am asking here. Also, while f is running I will not be pressing the button: I will wait until it stops. In addition, I want to get the output of 'f' from the running thread and the progress bar to close after finishing executing f to move on with life :). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should update your question with these information. I might look into it in the next days if you haven't got any good answer till there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

root = tk.Tk() # Main window

def create_command():
    # create a flag to stop the progress bar
    stop_flag = threading.Event()

    def f():
        print("Starting task...\n", end="")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Task complete.\n", end="")
        # set the stop flag to indicate that progress_check() should stop
        stop_flag.set()

    progress_bar_window = tk.Toplevel(root)

    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(progress_bar_window, orient="horizontal",
                                   length=300, mode="indeterminate")
    progress_bar.pack()
    progress_bar.start()

    def progress_check():
        # If the flag is set (function f has completed):
        if stop_flag.is_set():
            # Stop the progressbar and destroy the toplevel
            progress_bar.stop()
            progress_bar_window.destroy()
        else:
            # If the function is still running:
            print("Running infinite loop...\n", end="")
            # Schedule another call to progress_check in 100 milliseconds
            progress_bar.after(100, progress_check)

    # start executing f in another thread
    threading.Thread(target=f, daemon=True).start()
    # Start the tkinter loop
    progress_check()

create_button = tk.Button(root, text= "Create", command=create_command)
create_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Explanation:

To run a loop alongside `tkinter`, you should use `.after`, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801) question. I changed `progress_check` so that `tkinter` calls it every 100 milliseconds until `stop_flag` is set. When `stop_flag` is set, the progressbar stops and the `Toplevel` is destroyed.

---

A few minor points:

- `from ... import *` is discouraged
- With `tkinter`, you don't need more than 1 `.mainloop()` unless you are using `.quit()`. `.mainloop()` doesn't stop until all `tk.Tk` windows have been destroyed.
- There is no point in creating a new thread, if you are going to call `.join()` right after.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [don't use wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615206/13629335)!
Wildcard-imports can lead to name conflicts, for instance swap the wildcard imports from ttk and tkinter. You end up using tkinter buttons even if you want to use ttk buttons. Same issue might appear with `PhotoImage` and pillow. The magic word is ["qualified-names"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name).

Also I like to have some sort of structure in my code, I prefer classes. However, even in a procedural code there can be some sort of structure. For instance:

1. imports
   1.0) built-in modules
   1.1) import external modules
   1.2) import own modules
2. Constants and global variables
3. free functions
4. main window definitions
   ...

every logical block can be separated with comments that indicates what the following code might do or represents. This could also be useful to "jump" with the search function of your IDE to the point you want to work next, in larger scripts and modules this becomes handy.

---

A slightly different version of your code can be found below and **it is not intended to be used**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

def start_worker_thread():
    'This function starts a thread and pops up a progressbar'
    def generate_waiting_window():
        'nested function to generate progressbar'
        #disable button to inform user of intended use
        start_btn.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        #toplevel definitions
        toplevel = tk.Toplevel(root)
        toplevel.focus()
        #progressbar definitions
        progress = ttk.Progressbar(
            toplevel, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
        progress.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        progress.start()
        return toplevel

    def long_blocking_function():
        'This function simulates a long blocking call'
        stopped = threading.Event()
        n = 0
        while not stopped.is_set():
            n += 1
            print('working in turn', n)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            if n == 10:
                stopped.set()        
        nonlocal thread_info
        thread_info = n
        #important!! last logical line
        toplevel.destroy()
        return None
    
    toplevel = generate_waiting_window()
    thread_info = None
    thread = threading.Thread(target=long_blocking_function)
    thread.start()
    toplevel.wait_window()
    start_btn.configure(state='normal')
    result_lbl.configure(text='Result is: '+str(thread_info))
    print('thread exited on turn', thread_info)

#Main window definitions
root = tk.Tk()
start_btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start_worker_thread)
start_btn.pack()
result_lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Result is: None')
result_lbl.pack()
#start the application
root.mainloop()
#after application is destroyed
```

While this code is efficient for this simple task, it requires understanding what it does to debug it. That is why you won't find code like this often. **It is here for demonstrative purposes**. So what is wrong with the code and how does it differ from the meanwhile [**canonical way**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747734/13629335) of using threads in tkinter.

---

First of all, it uses nested function. While this might not an issue here, computing the same function over and over again, can slow down your code significantly.
Second it uses [`tkwait`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74370984/13629335) and therefore has some caveats over the linked answer.
Also `threading.Event` is a low-level primitive for communication, while there are cases you could use it, tkinter offers own tools for it and these should be preferred.
In addition it does not use a threadsafe storage for the data and this could also lead to confusion and non reliable data.

---

**A better approach and a slight improvement to the canonical way can be found here:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import sys
import queue
import time

inter_thread_storage = queue.Queue()
temporary_toplevel = None
EXIT = False

def on_thread_ended_event(event):
    start_btn.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    result = inter_thread_storage.get_nowait()
    result_lbl.configure(text='Result is: '+str(result))
    global temporary_toplevel
    temporary_toplevel.destroy()
    temporary_toplevel = None

def worker_thread_function():
    'Simulates a long blocking function'
    n = 0
    while n < 10 and not EXIT:
        n += 1
        print('working in turn', n)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if not EXIT:
        inter_thread_storage.put(n)
        root.event_generate('<<ThreadEnded>>')

def start_worker_thread():
    'This function starts a thread and pops up a progressbar'
    #toplevel definitions
    toplevel = tk.Toplevel(root)
    toplevel.focus()
    #progressbar definitions
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(
        toplevel, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
    progress.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    progress.start()
    #thread definitions
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker_thread_function)
    thread.start()
    #disable button to inform user of intended use
    start_btn.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    #store toplevel temporary
    global temporary_toplevel
    temporary_toplevel = toplevel

#Main window definitions
root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Destroy>',lambda e:setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'EXIT', True))
root.bind('<<ThreadEnded>>', on_thread_ended_event)
start_btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start_worker_thread)
start_btn.pack()
result_lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Result is: None')
result_lbl.pack()
#start the application
root.mainloop()
#after application is destroyed
```

This is how it works:

- [generate a new event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36238117/13629335)
- Make sure your toplevel can be reached, [with global or alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330720/13629335).
- store data threadsafe like in a Queue
- fire the event and let tkinter call your function safely in the mainloop.
- it has a flag for the edge case, where the user closes the main window before the thread finished.

Let me know, if you have questions to my answer.

Comment: Calling `tkinter` methods from threads other than the one where the `tk.Tk` was created isn't a good idea. Also what is the point of calling `wait_window`?

Comment: @TheLizzard you didn't read my answer. Did you ? There is some **bold** text in it.

Comment: Look at [this](https://pastebin.com/vKgnASu5), I modified your 2nd piece of code slightly and now it raises a `RuntimeError` if the main window is closed before the 2nd thread finishes. So I think that the statement "a slight improvement to the canonical way" is wrong.

Comment: @TheLizzard fair point, fixed it. Anything else ? Also note, that you could have multiple events for different tasks and these always ONLY go to work when needed. So I think it is an improvement.

Comment: This is just being nitpicky but theoretically (it will never happen in practise), if the user closes the main window just after the `event_generate` is called, the only reference to `root` will be in the second thread. Therefore, python's garbage collector will delete `root` from the second thread, which might crash python. That is why I always say to avoid calling `tkinter` methods from threads other than the `tk.Tk` thread.

Comment: @TheLizzard I also could fix that, but to make this example not more complicated as it needs to be, I'll leave it this way. For those who are interested in it, you can have a try and except block, filtering the message of the tcl error and ignore the specific case.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer and the tips on code structure (+1)!

Comment: @JohnD hopefully you once will notice how beneficial this approach is.